# Arraylist index out of bounds in lotto ticket class

Tags: java

I made a simple lottery game with 3 classes, one to create a lottery "ticket", one to create the objects to put in said class and another to test things. In my lottery ticket class, the user inputs 5 numbers and these numbers are added to a holder list where there's then a verification of several conditions to see where to place the number in the arraylist but for some reason, I'm getting an out of bound exception when I check index 1.

Leaving all classes below along with stacktrace

```
package jogoloto;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class LinhaCartao {
    ArrayList<NumeroLoto> Nums;
    ArrayList<Integer> holder;

    public LinhaCartao(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        Nums = new ArrayList<>(9);
        holder = new ArrayList<>();
        holder.add(n1);
        holder.add(n2);
        holder.add(n3);
        holder.add(n4);
        holder.add(n5);
            for(int n : holder){ 
                if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=1 && n<=9 || 
Nums.get(0) == null && n >=1 && n<=9){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(0,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=10 && n<=19 || 
Nums.get(1) == null && n >=10 && n<=19){ //EXCEPTION HERE
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(1,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=20 && n<=29 ||
Nums.get(2) == null && n >=20 && n<=29){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(2,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=30 && n<=39 || 
Nums.get(3) == null && n >=30 && n<=39){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(3,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=40 && n<=49 || 
Nums.get(4) == null && n >=40 && n<=49){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(4,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=50 && n<=59 || 
Nums.get(5) == null && n >=50 && n<=59){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(5,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=60 && n<=69 || 
Nums.get(6) == null && n >=60 && n<=69){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(6,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=70 && n<=79 || 
Nums.get(7) == null && n >=70 && n<=79){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(7,num);
                    
                }
                else if(Nums.isEmpty() && n >=80 && n<=89 || 
Nums.get(8) == null && n >=80 && n<=89){
                    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                    Nums.add(8,num);
                    
                }
                else System.out.println("N invalido");    
            }
    }
    
    public void imprimeLinha(){
        for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
            if(Nums.get(i).getNumero()>0){
                System.out.println(":"+Nums.get(i).getNumero()+":");
            }
            else if(Nums.get(i)== null){
                System.out.println(":_:");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void marcaNumeroAnunciado(int numero){
        for(NumeroLoto n : Nums){
            if(n.getNumero()==numero){
                n.setSaiu(true);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public int quantosNumerosPorMarcar(){
        int count = 0;
        for(NumeroLoto n : Nums){
            if(n.getEstado()==false){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    
    public boolean verificaLinhaCompleta(){
        int count = 0;
        for(NumeroLoto n : Nums){
            if(n.getEstado()==true){
                count++;
            }
            if(count==5){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public int limpaLinha(){
        int count = 0;
        for(NumeroLoto n : Nums){
            if(n.getEstado()==true){
                count++;
                Nums.remove(n);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

```
package jogoloto;

/**
 *
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class NumeroLoto {
    int numero;
    public boolean saiu;

    public NumeroLoto(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
        saiu = false;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    
    public boolean getEstado(){
        return saiu;
    }

    public void setSaiu(boolean saiu) {
        this.saiu = saiu;
    }  
}
```

```
public class JogoLoto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinhaCartao l = new LinhaCartao(1, 20, 45, 58, 71); //EXCEPTION WHEN I CALL CONSTRUCTOR
        l.imprimeLinha();
        l.quantosNumerosPorMarcar();
    }
    
}
```

stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at jogoloto.LinhaCartao.<init>(LinhaCartao.java:30)
    at jogoloto.JogoLoto.main(JogoLoto.java:14)
C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\14\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Nuno\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\14\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Indexes are 0 based. So if you array size is 9, the valid indexes are from 0 - 8 (not 9).

Comment: yes thats how I want it to be, in the code I only try to get up to the 8th index

Comment: `Nums = new ArrayList<>(9);` only creates an `ArrayList` with a *capacity* of 9. It's still empty, so `Nums.get(0)` will fail.

Comment: Try `Arrays.asList(new int[9])` instead to get a filled list with the length of 9. (default value is 0)

Comment: I already changed up my code to keep the arraylist empty by changing the ifs to (for example) `Nums.isEmpty() && n >=1 && n<=9 || Nums.get(0) == null && n >=1 && n<=9 ` but now I get a ConcurrentModifiedException at `for(int n : holder)`

Comment: Can you share the third class where you call / test / use this classes?

Comment: ok adding it now

Comment: Again, I fixed the exception by removing `holder.remove(n)`, but now I get an exception of out of bounds yet again but in another place now. commenting where it's happening.

Comment: @nuno ConcurrentModifiedException means you are changeing the content of the array while iterating trough it with your for loop.

Comment: Can you paste the entire stacktrace of your out of bounds exception?

Comment: yup adding it now

Comment: You didn't implement the solution I recommented above. This is still an empty list: ` new ArrayList<>(9)` as @JonSkeet said.

Comment: I understand that but won't the if statement check if it's empty and make that irrelevant?

Comment: And if I implement like you said, I have to keep ints in the list not NumeroLoto objects

Comment: Not realy because you are using an `or`. Your condition looks like this: `if A and B and C or D and E and F`. *And gets prioritized.* So lets say condition A fails because the list is empty it checks condition D which is your get from the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246256/discussion-between-japhei-and-nuno).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things way too much. There are obviously simpler approaches to achieve what you are trying to do. I will share a solition below where your code should work, with little modification in your current code as possible, but at the same time encourage you to refactor and try better aproaches.

**First issue**, the line `Nums = new ArrayList<>(9);` will not create a list with prefilled list having 9 values. It will just create an empty list (size == 0). 9 is just the initial capacity. change it to

```
Nums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null));
```

**Second issue** remove all `holder.remove(n)` calls. (which you have already done in between)

**third issue** use `Nums.add(index, n)` to put an element at a specific index, but you need to remove the null first so that your list size still remains 9

```
if(Nums.get(0) == null && n >=1 && n<=9){ 
    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
    Nums.remove(0);
    Nums.add(0, num);

}
else if(Nums.get(1) == null && n >=10 && n<=19){
    NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
    Nums.remove(1);
    Nums.add(1, num);

}
// ... and so on
```

**fourth issue** in your `imprimeLinha` method check for null first (change condition of `if` and `else if`) to avoid `NullPointerException`. If `Nums.get(i)` is null you cann't call `Nums.get(i).getNumero()>0` without an NPE

```
public void imprimeLinha(){
    for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        if(Nums.get(i)== null){
            System.out.println(":_:");
        }
        else if(Nums.get(i).getNumero()>0){
            System.out.println(":"+Nums.get(i).getNumero()+":");
        }
    }
}
```

**Fifth issue** in all other metods add a null check in your if condition for the same reason as above

```
public void marcaNumeroAnunciado(int numero){
    for(NumeroLoto n : Nums){
        if(n != null && n.getNumero()==numero){    // <- n != null
            n.setSaiu(true);
        }
    }
}
```

For easier access your whole code modified:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author Nuno
 */
public class LinhaCartao {

    ArrayList<NumeroLoto> Nums;
    ArrayList<Integer> holder;

    //1, 20, 45, 58, 71
    public LinhaCartao(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        Nums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null));
        holder = new ArrayList<>();
        holder.add(n1);
        holder.add(n2);
        holder.add(n3);
        holder.add(n4);
        holder.add(n5);
        for (int n : holder) {
            if (Nums.get(0) == null && n >= 1 && n <= 9) { 
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(0);
                Nums.add(0, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(1) == null && n >= 10 && n <= 19) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(1);
                Nums.add(1, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(2) == null && n >= 20 && n <= 29) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(2);
                Nums.add(2, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(3) == null && n >= 30 && n <= 39) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(3);
                Nums.add(3, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(4) == null && n >= 40 && n <= 49) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(4);
                Nums.add(4, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(5) == null && n >= 50 && n <= 59) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(5);
                Nums.add(5, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(6) == null && n >= 60 && n <= 69) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(6);
                Nums.add(6, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(7) == null && n >= 70 && n <= 79) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(7);
                Nums.add(7, num);

            } else if (Nums.get(8) == null && n >= 80 && n <= 89) {
                NumeroLoto num = new NumeroLoto(n);
                Nums.remove(8);
                Nums.add(8, num);

            } else {
                System.out.println("N invalido");
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprimeLinha() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (Nums.get(i) == null) {
                System.out.println(":_:");
            } else if (Nums.get(i).getNumero() > 0) {
                System.out.println(":" + Nums.get(i).getNumero() + ":");
            }
        }
    }

    public void marcaNumeroAnunciado(int numero) {
        for (NumeroLoto n : Nums) {
            if (n != null && n.getNumero() == numero) {
                n.setSaiu(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public int quantosNumerosPorMarcar() {
        int count = 0;
        for (NumeroLoto n : Nums) {
            if (n != null && n.getEstado() == false) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean verificaLinhaCompleta() {
        int count = 0;
        for (NumeroLoto n : Nums) {
            if (n != null && n.getEstado() == true) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 5) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int limpaLinha() {
        int count = 0;
        for (NumeroLoto n : Nums) {
            if (n != null && n.getEstado() == true) {
                count++;
                Nums.remove(n);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Sixth issue: use a lowercase variable name! `ArrayList<NumeroLoto> nums` (_not_ "Nums")

Comment: This is written very beginner-friendly but still very hardcoded...

Comment: Yeah I just got distracted and when I realized it I had already written the entire program that's why the variable name wasn't lower case haha

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the [discussion chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246256/discussion-between-japhei-and-nuno) the constructor can be rewritten as this:

```
public LinhaCartao(int...holder) { ///... means there can be as many parameters as wanted (stored as array)
    nums = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[9])); //list with the length of 9; default values are 'null' 
    for (int n : holder) {
        int firstDigit = n / 10; //the int division by 10. So e.g. 24 / 5 = 2 and 67 / 10 = 6
        nums.set(firstDigit, n); //overrides the position in the list with the number n
    }
}
```